# Update calendar data when entering new events

Tags: javascript

I insert new data this way, where in success I update the data:

```
function insertIntoDBrefe($o){

  $o.serializeArray();

  var dadosajax = {
    'reff' : $("#reff").is(":checked") ? $("#reff").val() : '',
    'reff1' : $("#reff1").is(":checked") ? $("#reff1").val() : '',
    'reff2' : $("#reff2").is(":checked") ? $("#reff2").val() : '',
    'almm' : $("#almm").is(":checked") ? $("#almm").val() : '',
    'almm1' : $("#almm1").is(":checked") ? $("#almm1").val() : '',
    'almm2' : $("#almm2").is(":checked") ? $("#almm2").val() : '',
    'almm3' : $("#almm3").is(":checked") ? $("#almm3").val() : '',
    'valref' : $("#valref").val(),
    'Dataref' : $("#Dataref").val(),
    'Datareff' : $("#Datareff").val()
  };
  $.ajax({
    url: 'regerpi.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: dadosajax,
    success: function(data){ 
      $('.fform')[0].reset();

      $.getJSON('consrefeicoes.php', function (datta) {

        for (var i = 0; i < datta.length; i++) {
      
          PequenoAlm = datta[i].PequenoAlm;
          Alm = datta[i].Alm;
          Lan = datta[i].Lan;
          jant = datta[i].jant;
          Ceia = datta[i].Ceia;
          Valencia = datta[i].Valencia;
          Ano = datta[i].Ano;
          Colaborador = datta[i].Colaborador;
          mes = datta[i].mes;
          dia = datta[i].dia;
          Data = datta[i].Data;
          Idm = datta[i].Id;

          var testees = [];
          var testees = [PequenoAlm, Alm, Lan, jant, Ceia];
        
          var testees1 = testees.filter(Boolean).join(', ');
            
          event_data.events.push({
            "occasion": testees1,
            "invited_count": Idm,
            "year": Number(Ano),
            "month": Number(mes),
            "day": Number(dia)
          })
            
        };
      
        init_calendar(new Date())
      
      });


    }
  });
}
```

This way updates the new events in the calendar, but duplicates the existing ones.

The init_calendar function:

```
function init_calendar(date) {
  $(".tbody").empty();
  $(".events-container").empty();
  var calendar_days = $(".tbody");
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var day_count = days_in_month(month, year);
  var row = $("<tr class='table-row'></tr>");
  var today = date.getDate();

  date.setDate(1);
  var first_day = date.getDay();

  for(var i=0; i<35+first_day; i++) {

    var day = i-first_day+1;

    if(i%7===0) {
        calendar_days.append(row);
        row = $("<tr class='table-row'></tr>");
    }

    if(i < first_day || day > day_count) {
        var curr_date = $("<td class='table-date nil'>"+"</td>");
        row.append(curr_date);
    }   
    else {
        var curr_date = $("<td class='table-date'>"+day+"</td>");
        var events = check_events(day, month+1, year);
        if(today===day && $(".active-date").length===0) {
            curr_date.addClass("active-date");
            show_events(events, months[month], day);
        }
  
        if(events.length!==0) {
            curr_date.addClass("event-date");
        }
      
        curr_date.click({events: events, month: months[month], day:day}, date_click);
        row.append(curr_date);
    }
  }

  calendar_days.append(row);
  $(".year").text(year);

  calendar_days.append(row);
  if(month == 0){
    $(".mes").text("Janeiro");
  }
  if(month == 1){
    $(".mes").text("Fevereiro");
  }
  if(month == 2){
    $(".mes").text("Março");
  }
  if(month == 3){
    $(".mes").text("Abril");
  }
  if(month == 4){
    $(".mes").text("Maio");
  }
  if(month == 5){
    $(".mes").text("Junho");
  }
  if(month == 6){
    $(".mes").text("Julho");
  }
  if(month == 7){
    $(".mes").text("Agosto");
  }
  if(month == 8){
    $(".mes").text("Setembro");
  }
  if(month == 9){
    $(".mes").text("Outubro");
  }
  if(month == 10){
    $(".mes").text("Novembro");
  }
  if(month == 11){
    $(".mes").text("Dezembro");
  }
    
}
```

I intend that when updating the new events it does not duplicate the previous ones.

I've also tried using this code inside success, but it doesn't work either:

```
$(".tbody").empty(); 
$(".events-container").empty();
```

In this question you have the complete code to generate the calendar with the events in the database:

[Question associated with this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76389075/return-data-from-database-and-show-in-calendar)

I've tried several times and none of them work, can anyone give me an idea of ​​what I have to do?